# Username Parameter In Sql Script c# Web Project Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql

I have a grid view in a web application in visual studio with a sql query attached to it. How do i pass the Username the person has logged in with into a parameter in the query

Comment: are you trying to update the database with a username or put new records into the database with the username?

Comment: i am trying to pull data from a table where the parameter is the name they have logged in with. So e.g select * from contact where name = @LoginName

Comment: If you are looking for the Windows username, I use C# to grab the username.  I've shown this below in an answer.

Comment: I just edited it to include how to find SQL-Server user_name

Comment: If a user logs into a website how would i pull that username they logged into a website with in a script

Comment: Several questions:  Do you have access to the webpage code the user logs in with?  What web languages are being used?  PHP?  MySQL?  Do you have a list of existing users in the database you want to compare their login with?  Do you want to add new users? Both?

Comment: yeah it's c# we have had a login page built for us to use on a sales dashboard. what i now want to do is put charts etc behind the login page that just pulls data for that one user that has logged in. Yeah we have a list of existing users in the database as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the user's input as a variable into the SQL Query using command.Parameters.AddWithValue(). Quick Example..

```
var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users (Username) VALUES (@Username)");

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text);

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the username the user is logged in with (in Windows) by executing:

```
String userName = Environment.UserName;
```

In your SQL query, you would use this variable like this:

```
String SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM [YourTable] WHERE colUserName = '" + userName + "';";
```

If you are looking for the username the person is logged into SQL-Server with (for example) you would use:

```
SELECT system_user;
```

to get:

```
String SQLQuery = "SELECT * FROM [YourTable] WHERE colUserName = system_user;";
```